# ESXi SOAP error

Tags: soap, esxi

i have some problems with my ESXi setup.
i have some connection( i think?) problems with ESXi, it worked like a charm for 8-9 hours, and then sudenly it stoped responding on ping or whatever, and all VM's on it.
 I have requested a hardware reboot, and it came back online normaly.
The only error i managed to found in ESXi log files is:

```
2014-12-24T08:54:26.662Z [6F2D1B70 error 'SoapAdapter.HTTPService.HttpConnection']      Failed to read header on stream <io_obj p:0x6dd76008, h:66, <TCP '0.0.0.0:0'>, <TCP '0.0.0.0:0'>>: N7Vmacore15SystemExceptionE(Connection reset by peer)
2014-12-24T08:54:40.019Z [6F290B70 verbose 'Statssvc.vim.PerformanceManager'] HostCtl Exception in stats collection.  Turn on 'trivia' log for details
2014-12-24T08:54:44.487Z [6F2D1B70 verbose 'Hostsvc.DvsManager'] PersistAllDvsInfo called
2014-12-24T08:55:00.019Z [6F2D1B70 verbose 'Statssvc.vim.PerformanceManager'] HostCtl Exception in stats collection.  Turn on 'trivia' log for details
2014-12-24T08:55:01.421Z [6EB84B70 verbose 'SoapAdapter'] Responded to service state request
2014-12-24T08:55:05.906Z [6CAC2B70 verbose 'Hostsvc.ResourcePool ha-root-pool'] Root pool capacity changed from 16625MHz/60595MB to 16625MHz/60593MB
2014-12-24T08:55:20.018Z [6F352B70 verbose 'Statssvc.vim.PerformanceManager'] HostCtl Exception in stats collection.  Turn on 'trivia' log for details
2014-12-24T08:55:40.019Z [6E5C1B70 verbose 'Statssvc.vim.PerformanceManager'] HostCtl Exception in stats collection.  Turn on 'trivia' log for details
2014-12-24T08:55:41.040Z [6E5C1B70 verbose 'Cimsvc'] Ticket issued for CIMOM version 1.0, user root
2014-12-24T08:56:00.019Z [6F352B70 verbose 'Statssvc.vim.PerformanceManager'] HostCtl Exception in stats collection.  Turn on 'trivia' log for details
2014-12-24T08:56:20.020Z [6E5C1B70 verbose 'Statssvc.vim.PerformanceManager'] HostCtl Exception in stats collection.  Turn on 'trivia' log for details
2014-12-24T08:56:40.018Z [6F290B70 verbose 'Statssvc.vim.PerformanceManager'] HostCtl Exception in stats collection.  Turn on 'trivia' log for details
2014-12-24T08:57:00.022Z [6E5C1B70 verbose 'Statssvc.vim.PerformanceManager'] HostCtl Exception in stats collection.  Turn on 'trivia' log for details
2014-12-24T08:57:05.910Z [6F290B70 verbose 'Hostsvc.ResourcePool ha-root-pool'] Root pool capacity changed from 16625MHz/60593MB to 16625MHz/60595MB
2014-12-24T08:57:12.273Z [6F290B70 verbose 'Cimsvc'] Ticket issued for CIMOM version 1.0, user root
2014-12-24T08:57:20.021Z [6F352B70 verbose 'Statssvc.vim.PerformanceManager'] HostCtl Exception in stats collection.  Turn on 'trivia' log for details
2014-12-24T08:57:40.020Z [6EB84B70 verbose 'Statssvc.vim.PerformanceManager'] HostCtl Exception in stats collection.  Turn on 'trivia' log for details
2014-12-24T08:58:00.019Z [6EB84B70 verbose 'Statssvc.vim.PerformanceManager'] HostCtl Exception in stats collection.  Turn on 'trivia' log for details
2014-12-24T08:58:20.021Z [6F290B70 verbose 'Statssvc.vim.PerformanceManager'] HostCtl Exception in stats collection.  Turn on 'trivia' log for details
2014-12-24T08:58:40.021Z [6F2D1B70 verbose 'Statssvc.vim.PerformanceManager'] HostCtl Exception in stats collection.  Turn on 'trivia' log for details
2014-12-24T08:58:43.492Z [6F290B70 verbose 'Cimsvc'] Ticket issued for CIMOM version 1.0, user root
2014-12-24T08:59:00.020Z [6F290B70 verbose 'Statssvc.vim.PerformanceManager'] HostCtl Exception in stats collection.  Turn on 'trivia' log for details
2014-12-24T08:59:05.914Z [6F2D1B70 verbose 'Hostsvc.ResourcePool ha-root-pool'] Root pool capacity changed from 16625MHz/60595MB to 16625MHz/60594MB
2014-12-24T08:59:20.020Z [6F2D1B70 verbose 'Statssvc.vim.PerformanceManager'] HostCtl Exception in stats collection.  Turn on 'trivia' log for details
2014-12-24T08:59:26.666Z [6F352B70 info 'Solo.Vmomi' opID=hostd-823b user=root] Activation [N5Vmomi10ActivationE:0x6d884c58] : Invoke done [waitForUpdatesEx] on [vmodl.query.PropertyCollector:ha-property-collector]
2014-12-24T08:59:26.666Z [6F352B70 verbose 'Solo.Vmomi' opID=hostd-823b user=root] Arg version:
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is more that a year old, but I have the sinilar issue. The symptoms are: esxi management interface is working and pingable, VMs are not, SSH to host is working but you can't stop VMs and such.
I found a bug http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2038767 that was reffered in this thread https://communities.vmware.com/message/2288283#2288283.